# cannot resolve method getmap() extends SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-studio

I have problem with this code, "cannot resolve method getMap(). I dont find where is the problem, please need help with code, I use Android Studio and need to take markers locations with Json.
i cannot understand how to update this code according too new changes. please correct this code according to new code,.

```
class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements IPageChanged {
    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";
    private String firstLine = null;
    private boolean isCountry;
    private CountryDetail mCountryData;
    private LocationData mLocationData;
    private CountryDetail preData;
    private float previousZoomLevel;
    private String secondLine = null;

    class C14782 implements InfoWindowAdapter {
        C14782() {
        }

        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        public View getInfoContents(Marker latLng) {
            View v = null;
            if (MapFragment.this.getActivity() != null) {
                v = MapFragment.this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
                TextView cap = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_cap);
                cap.setText(MapFragment.this.secondLine);
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_country)).setText(MapFragment.this.firstLine);
                TextView continent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_continent);
                ImageView ivflag = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_flag);
                if (MapFragment.this.isCountry) {
                    continent.setText(String.valueOf(MapFragment.this.mCountryData.getContinentName()));
                    ivflag.setImageBitmap(AppUtil.getFlag(MapFragment.this.getActivity(), MapFragment.this.mCountryData.getCode()));
                } else {
                    cap.setText(AppUtil.getStringResourceByName(MapFragment.this.getActivity(), "c" + MapFragment.this.secondLine));
                    continent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ivflag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }

    class C14793 implements OnInfoWindowClickListener {
        C14793() {
        }

        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Uri url = Uri.parse("http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + MapFragment.this.mLocationData.getName().replaceAll(" ", "_"));
            Intent urlIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            urlIntent.setData(url);
            MapFragment.this.getActivity().startActivity(urlIntent);
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LocationData locationData;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        Parcelable p = bundle.getParcelable("country");
        if (p == null) {
            locationData = (LocationData) bundle.getParcelable("location");
        } else {
            locationData = (LocationData) p;
            this.isCountry = true;
            if (locationData instanceof CountryDetail) {
                this.mCountryData = (CountryDetail) locationData;
            }
        }
        this.mLocationData = locationData;
    }

    private void dropPinEffect(Marker marker) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final Interpolator interpolator = new BounceInterpolator();
        final Marker marker2 = marker;
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                float t = Math.max(TextTrackStyle.DEFAULT_FONT_SCALE - interpolator.getInterpolation(((float) (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start)) / 1500.0f), 0.0f);
                marker2.setAnchor(0.5f, (14.0f * t) + TextTrackStyle.DEFAULT_FONT_SCALE);
                if (((double) t) > 0.0d) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 15);
                } else {
                    marker2.showInfoWindow();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateMapLocation() {
        if (this.mLocationData != null) {
            GoogleMap map = getMap();
            if (map != null) {
                map.clear();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng((double) this.mLocationData.getLatitude(), (double) this.mLocationData.getLongitude());
                if (this.isCountry) {
                    this.firstLine = this.mCountryData.getName();
                    this.secondLine = "©" + this.mCountryData.getCapital();
                } else {
                    this.firstLine = this.mLocationData.getName();
                    this.secondLine = this.mLocationData.getContinent();
                }
                Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(this.firstLine).snippet(this.secondLine));
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                if (this.preData == null || !this.mCountryData.getCode().equals(this.preData.getCode())) {
                    dropPinEffect(marker);
                } else {
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                }
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 3.0f));
                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(getInfoWindowClickListener());
                map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new C14782());
            }
        }
    }

    public OnInfoWindowClickListener getInfoWindowClickListener() {
        return new C14793();
    }

    public void onPageSelected(BaseActivity activity, int index) {
        if (index == 1 || !(activity instanceof CountryDetailActivity)) {
            updateMapLocation();
        }
        this.preData = this.mCountryData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have upgraded your google play service dependencies.The previously-deprecated getMap() function is no longer available in the Google Play services SDK. (It is still available in the Google Play services APK that is delivered to Android devices.) The getMap() function has been deprecated since December 2014. See the release blog post for help with converting from getMap() to getMapAsync().
More info https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases